# Websockets php перезагрузка страницы

Tags: websocket

Возникла такая проблема. Написал сервер-клиентское приложение с передачей данных по 2-стороннему соединению websockets. Работает это так. Я запускаю php файл из консоли, затем обновляю html-страницу и соединение устанавливается. Однако. Как только я пытаюсь перезагрузить страницу, соединение слетает и нужно делать рестарт php-файла с websockets.
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы данный процесс запускался на сервере (Apache) автоматически и при перезагрузке страницы переустанавливал соединение без ручного рестарта?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Видимо сначала скрипт весит в режиме ожидания клиента, потом общается с ним. И после завершения соединения скрипт также завершается. Алсо, без кода мы ничем не поможем.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что он не завершался как надо. Но сейчас вроде разобрался. В любом случае спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Под Apache не существует True FastCGI решения. Если решили что-то своё писать, то php-fpm (Nginx) Вам в помощь, но не [mod_php][1]. Существуют множество уже готовых демонов: NodeJS (JS), [PhpDaemon][2] (PHP), [dklab_realplexor][3] (PHP) - только Long Polling, Tornado (Python)...


  [1]: http://www.dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/49.html
  [2]: https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F
  [3]: http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/

Answer (score 1):

Решить проблему можно запуском демона на серваке. Если сервак на Linux, то надо просто подключиться по ssh и запустить ваш скрипт или через cli.

Если нет желания мучатся с конфигом то вот пример того как я запуская его на центосе:

```
nohup /usr/bin/php -f <тут путь к серверу>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я может не в тему скажу, но настоятельно советую использовать для этого nodejs. Вам будет намного удобней.
Установка займёт пару минут. И очень просто написать сервер.

Comment: да я бы не сказал. Вы во-первых предлагаете ТС перейти на другой язык, во вторых говорите неправду про пару минут.

Comment: На самом деле я немного поторопился. причина была видимо в цикле while, который крутился на сервере.

Comment: Насчет нового языка - не проблема. И js и java я знаю. Но насчет пары минут, да, обычно с новой технологией всё равно приходится повозиться поначалу, если, конечно, не просто копипастить откуда-то. Но потом и не настроишь как надо.

Comment: @luxor если знаешь java - то зачем для этих целей php?  в tomcat есть ws из коробки. всё готовое , проверенное. работает стабильно, рекомендую.